# React - Dynamic background colors to parent and child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In React, I have this components hierarchy:

```
App
  Header
  WaitingPage
    PlaceInLine
    NextRoom
    EstimatedTime
  Footer
```

I want the background of the elements to be: white-gray-white-gray and so. (For example - white Header, gray PlaceInLine, white NextRoom and so on...).
The problem is that in WaitingPage, it won't always have all of the 3 children. It gets data from the server, and, for example, if it gets place in line, it will show PlaceInLine. Another data can arrive while the website is running.

I tried to create a class called ColorGiver, which every time gives you the next color, but when I passed it as a prop to WaitingPage (after using it for getting the background for the Header), the header of the website and the first child of the WaitingPage where both white. I suppose that it's because of the order of how React renders elements, but I don't know exactly how it's done...

```
<Header backgroundColor={this.colorGiver.next()} />
<WaitingPage colorGiver={this.colorGiver} />
<Footer backgroundColor={this.colorGiver.next() />
```

What's the best way to implement that?

Comment: Please include what you have tried so far.

Comment: you can use @Jacek Walasik answer for the WaitingPage part. But I think you have to use js for the footer and make a css cumpted test to assign the color of the footer.

Answer (score 1):

Pure CSS would be pretty straight forward:

```
className:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
className:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}
```

Comment: Problem is that all elements are not on same level. @AviadBagno you can use this code for the inside of Waiting page

Comment: Yes. But then the inner order won't bee coordinated with the upper level, And it might happen that the last element of WaitingPage will be gray, and the Footer will be also gray..

Comment: Oh i kinda misundestood the issue, anyway since `Header` and `WaitingPage` are fixed only `Footer` color would change based on amount of `WaitingPage` children, id count them and check if number is odd or even.

Comment: OK, I will try it. Thank you!

Comment: Should I check the number of WaitingPage children using callback that called every time the amount of children is changed? Or there is a better way?